# Create a new column in dataframe by indexing into a list using another column?

Tags: r, list, indexing

I have a dataframe with a column of indices, and a list which maps each index to a value.

```
x <- data.frame( index = c("bob","tom","bob","harry") )
lst <- list( "bob" = 10, "tom" = 20, "harry" = 30 )
```

I would like to create a new column ("lookup") in the dataframe using the index column to lookup the appropriate value in the list. I thought something like ...

```
x$lookup <- lst[[ x$index ]] # nope, doesn't work
```

... might work, but that fails as an attempt of recursive indexing. The following works, but I'd like to avoid using a loop if possible:

```
for (i in 1:nrow(x) ) { # works, but is ugly
  x[ i, "lookup" ] <- lst[[ as.character( x[i,"index"] ) ]]
}
```

Yielding the following desired result:

```
> x
  index lookup
1   bob     10
2   tom     20
3   bob     10
4 harry     30
```

**Is there a way to accomplish this without using a loop?**

I was also caught by surprise that creating 'x' generated a dataframe column of factors rather than strings. **Is using the 'as.character' in the loop the best way to index properly into the list?**

New to both R and Stackoverflow, posting my first question after unsuccessfully trying to search for an answer. Apologies for my newness.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try `match`

```
 x$lookup <- unlist(lst[match(x$index, names(lst))])
 x
 #  index lookup
 #1   bob     10
 #2   tom     20
 #3   bob     10
 #4 harry     30
```

Or use `stack/merge`

```
  merge(x,stack(lst), by.x='index', by.y='ind')
```

Comment: Wow, you're crazy fast, thank you. I tried playing with your first idea, and tried avoiding using match. This seems to work, too:

`x$lookup <- unlist( lst[ as.character( x$index ) ] )`

Answer (score 2):

(Note: @JChou, the OP, found the correct form of this solution before I edited it into my answer.)

Using different brackets and a character index works:

```
x$index  <- as.character(x$index)
x$lookup <- unlist( lst[ x$index ] )
```

`[[` only accesses one element of a list at a time, while `[` subsets the list.

---

Alternately, you could keep `index` as a factor, but change its encoding to match that of the list. (Though I think this is too complicated to be a good idea.)

```
x$index  <- factor(x$index, levels=names(lst))
x$lookup <- unlist( lst[ x$index ] )
```

Comment: @akrun I was thinking of adding this to the answer, but figure I'll leave it down here instead: "The tedious workarounds are necessary because factors are the worst. I only find them useful for use with `table`."

Answer (score 1):

I did a blend of `stack` and `match`.

```
x$lookup <- stack(lst)$values[match(x$index, stack(lst)[,2])]
#  index lookup
#1   bob     10
#2   tom     20
#3   bob     10
#4 harry     30
```

Comment: I saw. I thought I was late to the party. You deleted yours?

Comment: I did delete it earlier, then thought that it might give some option, so undeleted.

Comment: I like yours though. cleaner